# How to enable indexing of pages with dynamic data?

Tags: architecture, indexing, hyperlink, web-crawler

I have a site that has certain urls that point to pages with permanent data and others that point to dynamic web pages. Google indexes both these regularly. By the time a user finds one of the dynamic content urls, the data on the page has already changed and the user does not find what he was looking for. Further, the dynamic url pages contains links to the permanent urls (which I want Google or any crawler to index). Google crawler controls (webmaster tools) cannot be made to read urls from a page but not index them. Solutions? *crawling strategies* *system architecture*.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the Google Webmaster FAQ:

**Q: I changed some text on my pages, why isn't it updated in the search results?**

**A**: Crawling and indexing of pages within a website can take some time. While there's no way to force an update, here are some tips that may help to speed this process up:

- If you have removed unique content (such as a name) from the page and need to have it updated as soon as possible, [removing the cached page with the URL removal tools](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=156412) may be a possibility.
- If you are using a [Sitemap](http://sitemaps.org/) file, make sure to update the [last modification date](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php#xmlTagDefinitions).
- If your site's content is indexed with multiple URLs, [resolving the duplicate content issue within your site](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/reunifying-duplicate-content-on-your.html) will generally allow crawlers to find updated content quicker.